# insert issue with auto-increment ID with Hibernate for a many to many association

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I use hibernate. My DB has a many to many relationship.
Hibernate generated these 2 classes to handle the relationship:

```
public class ExDuCours implements java.io.Serializable, IEmbededImproItem {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1017414L;
    private ExDuCoursId exDuCoursId; 
    private CoursImpro coursImpro;
    private ExImpro exImpro;
...
    @EmbeddedId

    @AttributeOverrides({ @AttributeOverride(name = "coursId", column = @Column(name = "Cours_Id", nullable = false) ),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "exId", column = @Column(name = "Ex_Id", nullable = false) ),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "duree", column = @Column(name = "Duree") ),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "commentaire", column = @Column(name = "Commentaire") ),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "Id", unique = true, nullable = false) )
    })
```

and:

```
@Embeddable
public class ExDuCoursId implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 10198474L;
    private int coursId;
    private int exId;
    private Integer duree=0;
    private String commentaire;
    private int id;
with id annotated this way:
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
```

If I try to save an instance, Hibernate will refuse because it does not recognize the Id field as an Identity.
I can understand this as the @AttributeOverrides does not specify it as @GeneratedValue .

I did not find anyway to set my ID as an Identity value:
            @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "Id", unique = true, nullable = false) )
If there is a way to do so, this is probably the solution to my problem.

The only alternate solution that I thought about was to move the ID field from class ExDuCoursId to ExDuCours...
I made some appropriate changes this way:

```
public class ExDuCours implements java.io.Serializable, IEmbededImproItem {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1017414L;
    private ExDuCoursId exDuCoursId;generated by hibernate, which contains the parameters
    private CoursImpro coursImpro;
    private ExImpro exImpro;
    private int id; //added the ID  field here!!
```

I commented both lines:
    //@EmbeddedId
//      @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "Id", unique = true, nullable = false) )

I removed all references to ID in class ExDuCoursId.

My demo stops fails with this error:
ERROR: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Ex_du_Cours_Cours_Impro". The conflict occurred in database "ImproDB", table "dbo.Cours_Impro", column 'Id'

Can anyone think about a solution?
There must be one as setupping a many to many relationship via hibernate must be extremely common.

Thx in advance.

Comment: Really, these entities are awful. Try generating them by yourself, by hand, and make sure they all have a single-column, auto-generated ID. 5 columns for an ID is really, really not something you want.

Comment: Well, I can give it a try if there s no fast solution.
What is the most awful in this auto-generated code according to you that should be particularily rewritten?

Would it make sense to completely get rid off the second class auto-created by hibernate (ExDuCoursId ) and move all its fields to class ExDuCours ?

Comment: Generating entities, in itself, is already absurd IMO. They're the core of your app, and should contain documentation, methods, etc. But the worst part of what you're showing are the IDs and the names. Why would an entity need 5 different fields, including functional and probably mutable fields like duree and commentaire, to identify it? An auto-generated Long ID is all you should need. Do you realize that you won't even be able to update the commentaire of an ExDuCours with that design? BTW, the naming, even in French, is also horrible. What does ExDuCours mean?

Comment: Well these 2 classes of course do contain several methods wih business code for my website. I only copy pasted here the fields declaration as it is what seems to cause the errors.
I have a table of exercices and a table of courses. Many to many associations : a course contains several ex. An ex can be contained into several courses. So I suppose I needed to create a tabe to link both entities. This is what ExDuCours is for. This table had some data of its own so I thought I could add a few more fields on top of the Exercice Id and the Course Id. Maybe it was not the proper place to do so?

Comment: As per the naming, I thought the good practise was to use CamelCase writing with uppercase for classes? As you can see I learnt the little that I know by my own and my self learning skill has is quite limited so apologize for all the noobs questions and thx for your time :)